# Applying two filters to a .net DataFrame

Tags: c#, dataframe, ml.net

Is there a more convenient way to apply two filters to a `DataFrame` in .net than this method?

```cs
DataFrame origFrame = DataFrame.LoadCsv("sample.csv");
var filtered1 = origFrame.Filter(origFrame ["Column1"].ElementwiseGreaterThanOrEqual(1000));
var filtered2 = filtered1.Filter(filtered1["Column2"].ElementwiseIsNotNull());
```

I tried chaining filters but that fails because in the 2nd call of Filter I would need to have access to the result of the first call of Filter. Adding both conditons in one Filter also did not work out since I could not find any method to create a `PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<bool>` with two conditons.

Comment: Python equivalent which you can do same in C# just a little tweak.

DataFrame origFrame = DataFrame.LoadCsv("sample.csv");
    
    
    def element_greater_than(element):
        return element >= 1000

    def element_is_not_none(element):
        return element is not None
        enter code here
    
    origFrame["Column1"] = origFrame["Column1"].apply(element_greater_than)
    
    origFrame["Column2"] = origFrame["Column2"].apply(element_is_not_none)
then create a new dataframe with the two modified colunmn.

Comment: Alternatively load your data and use Linq to filter then convert back to dataframe.